# Intuition of product spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So I have a product space of the form:

$X=X_1 \times \ldots \times X_n$

and I take two elements of it, say $x=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $x'=\{x_1',\ldots,x_n'\}$. Now suppose I take the following element:

$x''=x_1,\ldots,x_i',\ldots,x_n$

Can I guarantee that $x'' \in X$?

Comment: so you just changed the $i$th coordinate of $x$?

Comment: Yes, because for each $i$, $x^{\prime\prime}_i$ is an element of $X_i$.

Comment: Yes, unless there are other restrictions. The product space is all ordered sequences $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ where each $x_i\in X_i$.

Comment: Exactly, I just change one coordinate, forever mozart. Thinking it in terms of a plane, does it mean $X$ has an square structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An element of $X$ is just a sequence, the $i$th term of which is from $X_i$ for each $i$.

- Since $x\in X$, we know that the $k$th coordinate of $x''$ (which is $x_k$) is in $X_k$ - for every $k$ *except $k=i$*.
- However, since $x'\in X$, we know that $x_i'$ is in $X_i$.
- So each of the coordinates of $x''$ are in the corresponding factor space.

It may be more helpful to consider a concrete example: e.g. $X_1=\{4, 5, 6\}$, $X_2=\{7, 8, 9\}$, and $X_3=\{10, 11, 12\}$. Then let $x=(4, 7,10)$, $x'=(5, 8, 11)$, and $i=2$; then $$x''=(4, 8, 10).$$ Do you see why $x''$ is still in $X_1\times X_2\times X_3$?

Comment: Yep, thanks. I conclude that a product space must have some sort of square structure, even in higher dimensions. Thank you all!

Comment: @JosuéOrtega That's not necessarily wrong, but it may also be misleading. Here's an example: let $S^1$ be the unit circle (so, the set of pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$). Then the product space $S^1\times S^1$ is . . . a donut! (Or "torus" to sound more impressive.) I think this is a good example for getting intuition about product spaces.

Comment: A side note about possibly misleading notation (read this *after* you're comfortable with the previous comment): sadly, the name for $S^1\times S^1$ is **not** $S^2$. $S^2$ refers to the unit *sphere*, that is, the set of *triples* of real numbers $(x, y, z)$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. The name for $S^1\times S^1$ is $T^2$, "$T$" for "torus." (This is a little less silly than it looks: another name for $S^1$ is "$T^1$." The one-dimensional sphere and one-dimensional torus are the same thing!)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
x=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\in X\Longrightarrow&\,x_m\in X_m\quad\forall m\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\
x'=\{x_1',\ldots,x_n'\}\in X\Longrightarrow&\,x_m'\in X_m\quad\forall m\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\
\hline
\left.\begin{array}{c}x_1\in X_1\\\vdots\\x_i'\in X_i\\\vdots\\x_n\in X_n\end{array}\right\}\Longrightarrow&\,x''=\{x_1,\ldots,x_i',\ldots,x_n\}\in X_1\times\cdots\times X_i\times\cdots\times X_n=X
\end{align*}